# QGraphicsSVGItem ignores (some) clipping paths. Why?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicssvgitem

[This SVG image](https://framapic.org/LDdkxITWOZt8/AVgTisyTRGaQ.svg)  is correctly rendered in Firefox and Inkscape, but for some reason, when using `QGraphicsSVGItem` without anything fancy, it renders this way:

[image: b7438226-8ead-4e81-b541-9888b03058e9-image.png]

For reference, this is what it looks like on firefox:

[image: 83ecb93a-bfdf-45fc-b41c-5255655ae7e3-image.png]

As you can see, the back of the card is not supposed to go beyond the white border.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a (preferably easy) fix?

MWE:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, Qt, QtGui

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
scene.addItem(Qt.QGraphicsSvgItem("back-red.svg"))

graphics_view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
graphics_view.setScene(scene)
graphics_view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Your code is correct, it is a limitation of Qt Svg. What is your real goal? Maybe I could point you to another solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My real goal is to display several of these SVGs in my graphicsview, with correctly rounded corners and "corner transparency" to show the other items below this card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your svg does not meet the characteristics that Qt uses (for more information read [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/svgrendering.html#rendering-svg-files)). One possible solution is to use QWebEngineView(`python -m pip install pyqtwebengine`):

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSvg, QtWebEngineWidgets

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "back-red.svg")

    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()

    renderer = QtSvg.QSvgRenderer(filename)

    graphics_view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
    graphics_view.setScene(scene)
    graphics_view.show()

    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    view.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
    # view.page().setBackgroundColor(QtGui.QColor("transparent"))
    view.resize(renderer.viewBox().size())
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))

    item = scene.addWidget(view)

    graphics_view.resize(640, 480)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thank you for the link and the piece of code. Unfortunately this does not work for me. I display many items like this in my `QGraphicsView` (it's a deck of cards) and instantiating so many `QWebEngineView`s blows RAM usage out of proportions. Plus, even when trying to do so, the corners end up white instead of transparent. I guess the right way is to fix these SVGs to make them Qt-compliant. I will try to see if I can automate this

Comment: Figured this out by opening/exporting using tiny svg profile in illustrator. Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction!